# Hibernate thread-safe collections

Tags: java, multithreading, hibernate, collections

This is somewhat of a continuation of [Hibernate session thread safety](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20150110/2517719).  All of the details apply here as well.  In simplified terms, execution follows the pattern of:

```
1. Read entity
2. Do expensive, easily parallelizable work
3. Persist changes
```

The entities are all configured for eager loading, and the session is not accessed at all during 2.

The work involved in `2` requires infrequent modification of a persistent collection.  This is what I have now:

```
synchronized (parentEntity) {
    parentEntity.getChildEntities().add(childEntity);
}
```

This works just fine, but I'm trying to "idiot-proof" this system and I'm looking for a way to move the concurrency control as far down into the persistence layer as I can.  I've tried this in the dao:

```
@Transactional
public ParentEntity getParentEntityById(long id) {
    ParentEntity parent = ...;
    parent.setChildren(Collections.synchronizedSet(parent.getChildren()));
    return parent;
}
```

Which results in `org.hibernate.HibernateException: A collection with cascade="all-delete-orphan" was no longer referenced by the owning entity instance...`

Does anybody have a way to introduce thread-safety to hibernate collections, or some other clean way to control concurrent access and modification in a way that doesn't require polluting the business logic?

**Update**-  Here is what I ended up doing, per Pace's suggestion:

```
@Transactional
public ParentEntity getParentEntityById(long id) {
    ParentEntity parent = ...;
    currentSession().evict(parent);
    parent.setChildren(Collections.synchronizedSet(parent.getChildren()));
    return parent;
}
```

After the work is done, I save all of the children and call `currentSession().merge(parent)`.  Works like a charm!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Read the entity
2. Detach the entity
3. Do expensive, easily parallelizable work
4. Merge the entity
5. Commit the transaction

If step 3 takes any significant amount of time then I would recommend simply:

1. Open a session (could be read-only)
2. Read the entity(ies)
3. Close the session
4. Do expensive, easily parallelizable work
5. Open a new session
6. Merge the entity(ies)
7. Close the session

While detached/unattached you *should* be able to wrap the collections in thread safe collections.  The merge should not care what collection implementation you have.  I have not tested it however.